# Why does it put on record that I had a edit rejected, if it conflicted with a later one?

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

If I do an edit, and while it is pending (being approved), someone comes and does the same edit, my edit gets rejected by 'Community'. It doesn't contribute to my edit ban, but it does still contribute to my 'number of rejected edits', which is shown to all the reviewers when I edit something. This seems pointless, as in fact, my edit was good, and was, in a way, implemented. I shouldn't be penalised for it.

I don't think that this should increment the rejected edits number for no reason, even if it still doesn't award the +2 rep and increment the accepted edits number either.

Comment: Well, technically, it was rejected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yes but the way it is worded implies that he edit was bad, whereas in fact, it was so good that someone else also did it!

Comment: Well, my old request has the same goal then.

Answer (score 3):

> I shouldn't be penalised for it.

Well, you aren't. They are not counted against you. The problem is perception: users seeing that statistic don't know these kind of situations and just see the number of rejected edits.

So prevent users from judging you on this, I would say there are two options:

- The status is changed from *Rejected* to something else, like *Invalidated*;
- The number of Rejected edits by Community aren't counted there either.

I would say the first option is the better one since it is easier to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: Great minds think alike... see dupe. ;-)

Comment: Ah, yeah. I was just reading it. Good suggestion!