# Why isn't it stated in this review that someone rejected and edited the suggested edit?

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I recently came across [this suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50033) which was rejected by Community♦ for the reason:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

That rejection reason is usually used when a user reviews the edit as Reject and Edit. However, it says nowhere in the review that someone rejected and edited it ([which it usually does](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15856050)):

[image]

This seemed strange, so I took a look in the edit history of the post to see what happened. And there I noticed that [someone edited the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/164900/77) at exactly the same time as the suggested edit got rejected:

[image]

I also looked at [Nathan Tuggy's profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274165/nathan-tuggy?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=4) to see if the review was listed in there, but it wasn't.

So my guess is that Community♦ rejected the edit because Nathan Tuggy reviewed it as Reject and Edit.

Another possibility is that he submitted and independent edit [and the suggestion got rejected because of that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289997/349538), but the problem with that is that usually when this happens Community♦ says "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit" instead ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15082809)).

So if Nathan Tuggy reviewed the edit as Reject and Edit, why isn't it visible anywhere that he rejected and edited it? And if he submitted an independent edit, why does Community♦ give the message for rejected and edited edits instead of the one for edits that conflicted with another edit?

Comment: I would assume it was a conflict (so Nathan didn't review but instead submitted an independent edit) see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289997/

Comment: @Cai Maybe, but in that case usually Community says "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit." ([here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15082809)). But I will edit my question to add that possibility.

Comment: Hmm yeh fair point, not sure what's going on there then

Comment: I can confirm that I found the post to edit from the Suggested Edit queue and hit Reject and Edit because I had a better way to handle the observed problem in the text. But the review does not show up at all in my review history or in my profile. Probably a bug related to the [very recent change allowing rejected changes to be re-applied by the post author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028).